# OpenGL on Android - Texture Mapping - Only top left pixel visible on screen

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am trying to understand the concept of texture mapping. I tried to map a texture onto a square ( made up of 2 triangles ). However only the top left pixel of the image is rendered onto the square completely. Why does this happen? I have seen [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920118/opengl-on-android-texture-mapping-only-top-left-pixel-visible) with the same issue .. but that solution doesnt work for me

Initial Setup

```
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);               //Disable dithering ( NEW )
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);            //Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            //Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    //Black Background
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);                     //Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            //Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);             //The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
```

vertex coords -

```
    private float[] _vertices = {0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f,
                            60.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                            0.0f, 60.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
                            60.0f, 60.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
```

texture coords -

```
    private float _texCoords[] = {0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f };
```

Load texture method -

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context) {
    //Get the texture from the Android resource directory
    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(com.mhoapps.bugswatter.R.drawable.crate);
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        //BitmapFactory is an Android graphics utility for images
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    } finally {
        //Always clear and close
        try {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    // Generate one texture pointer...
    gl.glGenTextures(1, _textures, 0);
    int mTextureId = _textures[0];

    // ...and bind it to our array
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureId);

    // Create Nearest Filtered Texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GL10.GL_LINEAR);


    // Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image
    // from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);       //Clean up


    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Finally the draw method

```
    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    //Bind the texture according to the set texture filter

    //gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);



    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textures[0]);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _currentVertexBuffer);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, _bugTexBuffer1);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

Comment: Show us your relevant code. Without it we can only guess. And when mentioning another post, at least link to it.

Comment: [Mentioned question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920118/opengl-on-android-texture-mapping-only-top-left-pixel-visible)

Comment: FYI: In OpenGL you don't do a "initial" setup. Especially those state you set there actually should be set in the drawing function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifying your texture coordinates? It sounds like you aren't, and they are just defaulting to (0, 0). Another options is the texture matrix - are you setting that to all zeroes?

Comment: I've added the code above. I think I'm setting the tex coords here. Then convert it to floatbuffer.

Comment: oops..your point is entirely right. Instead of glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY), I had used glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) and pathetically wasted 3 hours!